pi-gen, installing nexmon on all kernel modules
I am trying to install Nexmon on all kernel modules:
#!/bin/bash -e

NEXMON_REPO=https://github.com/DrSchottky/nexmon.git
NEXMON_PATCHES="patches/bcm43430a1/7_45_41_46/nexmon patches/bcm43455c0/7_45_206/nexmon patches/bcm43436b0/9_88_4_65/nexmon"

for mod in $(cd /lib/modules ; ls); do
    pushd /usr/local/src
    echo "=== cloning nexmon repository"
    git clone ${NEXMON_REPO}
    cd nexmon

    echo
    echo ">>>---> building Nexmon for {mod}"

    export QEMU_UNAME=${mod}

    echo "++++ uname = ${mod}"
    source setup_env.sh
    make
    
    for p in ${NEXMON_PATCHES}; do
        echo "    ===--->  build ${mod} patch $p"
        pushd /usr/local/src/nexmon/$p
        make
    done

    echo cp /usr/local/src/nexmon/patches/driver/brcmfmac_6.6.y-nexmon/brcmfmac.ko /lib/modules/${mod}/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
    cp /usr/local/src/nexmon/patches/driver/brcmfmac_6.6.y-nexmon/brcmfmac.ko /lib/modules/${mod}/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko

    pushd /lib/modules/${mod}/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/
    mv brcmfmac.ko.xz brcmfmac.ko.xz.ORIG
    
    echo "++> Installed ${mod} kernel driver"
    echo
    echo "++> depmod ${mod}"
    /sbin/depmod ${mod}

    make clean

done

rm -r /usr/local/src/nexmon

ln -sf /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin /usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43436s-sdio.bin


But for some reason when it is building for the v8 version, I see it is using the 2712 modules folder:

How do I get it to actually use the v8 modules folder, I suspect the export QEMU_UNAME is not working as I expected it.
